# using ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteNonQuery 

Tags: c#, mysql

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
                    (@"INSERT INTO Table(field) VALUES('somevalue');" +
                    "SELECT * FROM table",cn);
```

This works fine to me since I'm only passing those statements to my MySQL server.

Is it OK to use `ExecuteReader()` when inserting & updating & deleting?

I usually use `ExecuteNonQuery()` on those.

Comment: Hopefully your real code does not actually select all the rows from the table upon every insert.  That will scale...poorly.

Comment: It will really kill it's performance if I try to 'SELECT' FROM whole table. I just set that as an example

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLCommand.ExecuteReader() does not restrict to read only statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348012/sqlcommand-executereader-does-not-restrict-to-read-only-statements)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're just fine bundling the extra INSERT in along with your SELECT with ExecuteReader().  This is okay.

I do see two things that are potentially not okay... nothing in the code itself, but what you showed is simplified, and the simplified code hints at some potential poor practices:

The first not okay is that your code looks like it *might* be using string concatenation to substitute values into your query. Something like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
                (@"INSERT INTO Table(field) VALUES('" + somevariable + "');" +
                "SELECT * FROM table",cn);
```

That is a **huge** problem, as it opens a gaping security hole in your application.  Instead, you need to use query parameters, so the code looks more like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
                (@"INSERT INTO Table(field) VALUES(@somevalue);" +
                "SELECT * FROM table",cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@somevalue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = somevariable;
```

The other potential problem is that your command and, more importantly, your connection, should be wrapped in a try/finally block (or for preference a using block), like this:

```
using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("..."))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("@INSERT INTO Table(field).... ", cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(...);
    cn.Open();
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I always pass the 'user' input at parameter to avoid SQL injection and practice the exception handling. I just cite this one as an example. Since, it's okay to throw batch queries to my server. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 4):

> **ExecuteReader**
>
> Do not use: when database query is going to provide for sure exactly 1
>   record.
>
> Use: when database query is going to provide a set of records. It may
>   be search or report.
>
> **ExecuteNonQuery**
>
> Use: when we are talking about a single database record - in Update,
>   Insert, Delete and Get by Id.
>
> **ExecuteScalar**
>
> Do not use: when database query returns a single value and this value
>   can be defined as parameter in T-SQL. ExecuteNonQuery with output
>   parameter(s) is always preferred in this case since it is more
>   flexible, tomorrow there will be 2 values therefore having
>   ExecuteNonQuery we do not need to change method signatures.
>
> Use: when database query returns a single value and this value cannot
>   be defined as output parameter, because of T-SQL type limitation for
>   variables.

[Reference](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/05/01/3049.aspx)

Comment: The OP is referencing a `MySqlCommand` class for MySQL, rather than SQL Server.

Comment: Dubious advice: 'use ExecuteNonQuery with output params when selecting exactly 1  record'? Wait wait wait. You're actually suggesting we declare *n* output params for each column in a given single result row? Brutal on the maintenance developer.

Answer (score 1):

If, for the sake of structuring, you have to use `ExecuteReader` then go ahead, just remember to dispose of (Close) the reader afterwards. It has a little effect on the program, but it is most likely limited to the .Net part, mostly just the memory consumption of an additional class instance. In fact, certain ADO.Net providers use `ExecuteReader` behind `ExecuteNonQuery` internally.

The bigger problem here is the `SELECT * FROM table` part after your insert query. Even though you're not using the reader to read the data, it still consumes more resources to execute a select query. Here, there should be no difference on the MySQL side whether you use `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteNonQuery` (unless you read from the reader, of course)